# Unity Analytics doesn't show new data

Tags: unity-game-engine, analytics

I'm integrating Unity Analytics in my project.

When I'm looking in the Validator I can see data like `appStart` and `appRuning` but from 08/06/2018 (more the 2 weeks ago), but nothing from today or the last week.

I tried adding an Analytics Event Tracker to a scene with a static value, just to see I the validator will show it, but nothing.

Why can't I see data in the validator?

Comment: In English, it's improper grammar to use spaces before `,` and `?` as you have done.